# How to Apply filters to dynamic product fields

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a question about applying dynamic filters to each category.
Suppose that there are different categories on the site and each category includes features (for example: shoes including size, material, etc., and the next category of the car includes engine size, etc.)
In addition, at the discretion of the admin, some filters may include a range of numbers instead of a selection (for example: vehicle odometer filter)

Note: The Below code is just for explain my path and my main question is in the repository (last code section) in Region Dynamic Filter.

Below you see the model

```
 public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string EnglishTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(650)]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnglishCategoryAvailable { get; set; }
    public bool IsPersianCategoryAvailable { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }

    #region Relationss

    public List<Product.Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryLocalization> CategoryLocalizations { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryPropertyLocalization> CategoryPropertyLocalizations { get; set; }

    #endregion


}

public class CategoryPropertyLocalization
{
    [Key]
    public string CategoryPropertyLocalizationId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryLocalizationId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300)]
    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(450)]
    [Required]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public bool HasARange { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    #region Relations
    public CategoryLocalization CategoryLocalization { get; set; }
    public Languages Languages { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    #endregion

}

 public class CategoryLocalization
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryLocalizationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(9000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string TitleTab { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(650)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }


    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }


    #region Relations
    [ForeignKey("Languages")]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Languages Languages { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryPropertyLocalization> CategoryPropertyLocalizations { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Below you see the ViewComponent Filters

```
@model List<KMMSCo.Application.ViewModels.PropertyCategoryViewModel>
@{
    var count = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="bg-white my-3 ">
        <ol class="list-group shadow filter-shop ">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" id="li@(++count)">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                    <div class="fw-bold">@item.Key</div>
                </div>
                <span class="badge rounded-pill">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down text-black text-start fa-2x" id="arrow-down-list@(count)"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li id="li@(count)_list" style="display: none">
                @if (item.HasARange)
                {
                    <div class="form-group mx-3 my-3">
                        <label>@item.Key از:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paramsProperty[@x][@y]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-3 my-3">
                        <label>@item.Key تا:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paramsProperty[@(x++)][@(++y)]" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-grid my-3 mx-4 ">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-white shadow">اعمال</button>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mx-1" id="myUL@(count)">
                        <li>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3 px-2 mt-3">
                                <span class="input-group-text bg-light">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass text-dark "></i>
                                </span>
                                <input id="myInput@(count)" name="paramsProperty[@(x++)]" onkeyup="myFunction@(count)()" placeholder="جست و جوی @item.Key" class="form-control text-start bg-light" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        @foreach (var values in item.Value)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values))
                            {
                                <li class="mx-3 mb-2 li-list-color@(count)">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="">
                                        <label>@values</label>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>}
```

You can see the controls below

```
[Route("{culture:culture}/shop/{category?}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string category, int pageId = 1, string filter = "",
            List<int> countryId = null, List<string> brandId = null, string orderByType = "date",
            int startPrice = 0, int endPrice = 0, List<int> selectedGroups = null, List<int> numbersProperty = null, string[][] paramsProperty = null)
        {
            var dynamicFilter = HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            var languageId = 0;
            if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "fa-IR")
            {
                ViewBag.DollerPrice = await _basicService.GetLastDollarPrice();
                languageId = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                languageId = 2;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
            {
                var selectCategory = await _categoryService.GetCategoryByUrl(category.ToLower(), languageId);

                if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "fa-IR")
                {
                    ViewBag.category = selectCategory.Title;
                    ViewBag.categoryId = selectCategory.CategoryId;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.category = selectCategory.EnglishTitle;
                }

                if (selectCategory != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.pageId = pageId;
                    var properties =
                        await _categoryService.GetPropertyCategoryByCategoryId(languageId, selectCategory.CategoryId);

                    if (dynamicFilter.HasValue)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < paramsProperty.Length; i++)
                        {
                            var list = new List<string>();
                            for (var j = 0; j < paramsProperty[i].Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (paramsProperty[i][j] != null)
                                {
                                    list.Add(paramsProperty[i][j]);
                                }
                            }
                            properties[i].Value = list;
                        }
                    }

                    return View(await _shopService.GetProductsList
                    (pageId, selectCategory.Title, properties, filter, countryId, languageId, brandId, orderByType, startPrice, endPrice,
                        selectedGroups));
                }

                return RedirectToAction("NotFoundPage");
            }

            ViewBag.pageId = pageId;
            return View(await _shopService.GetProductsList
            (pageId, category, filter, countryId, languageId, brandId, orderByType, startPrice, endPrice,
                selectedGroups));
        }
```

You can see the service below

```
  public async Task<Tuple<List<ShowProductCardViewModel>, int>> GetProductsList(int pageId = 1, string categoryName = null, List<PropertyCategoryViewModel> properties = null, string filter = "", List<int> countryId = null, int languageId = 1, List<string> brandId = null, string orderByType = "date",
            int startPrice = 0, int endPrice = 0, List<int> selectedGroups = null)
        {
            var lists = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < properties[i].Value.Count; j++)
                    {
                        lists.Add(properties[i].Key + ":" + properties[i].Value[j]);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

            }
            var products = await _shopRepository.GetProductsList(pageId, categoryName, lists, filter, countryId, languageId, brandId, orderByType, startPrice,
                endPrice, 10, selectedGroups);


            var counter = 0;
            var mapProducts = _mapper.Map<List<ShowProductCardViewModel>>(products.Item1);
            foreach (var item in mapProducts)
            {
                item.MainImage = await _productService.GetImageProductByProductId(item.ProductId);
                item.CategoryId = await _productService.GetCategoryIdByProductId(item.ProductId);
                item.Price = products.Item1[counter].Product.Price;
                counter++;
            }
            return Tuple.Create(mapProducts, products.Item2);
        }
```

Below you can see the repository code.

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<ProductLocalization>, int>> GetProductsList(int pageId, string categoryName, List<string> properties, string filter, List<int> countryId
            , int languageId,
            List<string> brandId, string orderByType,
            int startPrice, int endPrice, int take = 0, List<int> selectedGroups = null)
        {
            if (take == 0)
            {
                take = 8;
            }

            IQueryable<ProductLocalization> result = _context.ProductLocalizations
                .Include(c => c.ProductPropertyLocalizations)
                .Include(c => c.Product)
                .Include(c => c.Product.Brand)
                .Include(c => c.Product.Category)
                .Include(c => c.Product.Category.CategoryPropertyLocalizations)
                .Where(c => c.LanguageId == languageId);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            {
                result = result.Where(p => p.Title.Contains(filter) || p.Product.Brand.Title.Contains(filter));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName))
            {
                result = result.Where(p => p.Product.Category.Title.Contains(categoryName) || p.Product.Category.EnglishTitle.Contains(categoryName));
            }
            if (brandId.Count != 0)
            {
                result = result.Where(c => brandId.Contains(c.BrandId));
            }

            if (countryId.Count != 0)
            {
                result = result.Where(c => countryId.Contains(c.Product.CountryId));
            }

            if (startPrice > 0)
            {
                result = result.Where(p => p.Product.Price > startPrice);
            }
            if (endPrice > 0)
            {
                result = result.Where(p => p.Product.Price < endPrice);
            }

            #region Dynamic Filter

            var lists = new List<ProductPropertyLocalization>();
            //foreach (var item in properties)
            for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = properties[i].Split(":");

                for (int j = 0; j < value.Count(); j++)
                {

                    var get = await _context.ProductPropertyLocalizations.Where(c =>
                        c.Key == value[0] && c.Value == value[1]).ToListAsync();
                    //foreach (var item in get)
                    //{
                    //   == item.ProductLocalizationId);
                    //}
                    //if (get.Count == 0)
                    //{
                    //    result = null;
                    //    return Tuple.Create(result.ToList(), 0);
                    //}
                    result = result.Where(c => c.ProductPropertyLocalizations.Contains(get));
                }



                //var get = await _context.ProductPropertyLocalizations.Where(c =>
                //    c.Key == value[0] && c.Value == value[1]).ToListAsync();


                //lists.Add(_context.ProductPropertyLocalizations.Where(c =>
                //    c.Key == value[0] && c.Value == value[1]).ToList());

                //result = result.Where(c => c.ProductPropertyLocalizations[i].Value == value[1]);

            }

            #endregion



            switch (orderByType)
            {
                case "date":
                    {
                        result = result.OrderByDescending
                                (p => p.CreateDate);
                        break;
                    }
                case "lowPrice":
                    {
                        result = result.OrderBy(p => p.Product.Price);
                        break;
                    }
                case "highPrice":
                    {
                        result = result.OrderByDescending(p => p.Product.Price);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            int skip = (pageId - 1) * take;
            int pageCount;

            if (result.Count()>0)
            {
                pageCount = result.Count() / take + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                pageCount = 0;
            }



            return Tuple.Create(result.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList(), pageCount);
        }
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? Could you pls explain for more details?

Comment: I came up with a solution using any (any) filter
In fact, I wanted to output the subscription of the two lists